# view does not update with either scope or controller properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some trouble identifying a view update that is not happening neither when I set a property on the `$scope` nor when I set a property on the controller prototype.

I have create a quick [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NDsswyqG7YgBuSJeSkt6?p=preview) of what I am doing to illustrate the issue.

I have, for instance the following view:

```
<html data-ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.18" data-semver="1.2.18" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

        <div data-catalog="{ 'type': 'Category1', 'key': '252' }">

            <span class="text-danger">{{query | json}}</span>
            <span class="text-danger">{{catalog.model | json}}</span>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And a simple module with a directive and a controller:

```
angular
    .module("test", [])
    .controller("CatalogCtrl", ["$scope", "$parse", "$location", "$q", function ($scope, $parse, $location, $q) {

        var catalog = this,
            listener = function () {

                var query = {},
                params = $location.search();

                try
                {
                    query = $parse($scope.query)();
                }
                catch (exception)
                {
                    console.error(exception);
                }

                if (_.isEmpty(query))
                {
                    return;
                }

                $q
                    .all([
                        scroll({ top: 0 }),
                        Catalog.searchProducts(_.assign(query, params))
                    ])
                    .then(function (response) {
                        catalog.model = response[1];

                        console.log(catalog.model, response[1]);
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        catalog.model = {};
                    })
                    .finally(function () {});
            };

        catalog.model = {test:""};

        //$scope.listen("$locationChangeSuccess", listener);
    }])
    .directive("catalog", function () {

        return {
            controller: "CatalogCtrl as catalog",
            scope: {
            query: "@catalog"
            },
            restrict: "A",
            replace: false
        };
    });
```

The issue is that neither `{{query | json}}` nor `{{catalog.model | json}}` are rendered in the view and I am not sure what is the cause of it. It might be something I am missing or doing wrong, but I could use some help with it if anyone spots my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code...

**1.**

Your directive has it controlelr attached and you place some values on its scope (query, catalog etc). Then you try to access those values from an element that is outside of the directive (and thus has a different scope that knows nothing about `query`, `catalog` etc. E.g.

```
<!-- Let's say somehow DIV#1 has scope $001 -->
<div id="1">

    <!-- Somehow DIV#1.1 creates a new scope ($002) -->
    <div id="1.1" some-directive>

        <!-- DIV#1.1.1 will have access to scope $002 -->
        <!-- (under certain cirsumstances) -->
        <div id="1.1.1"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- DIV#1.2 (which is outside of DIV#1.1) -->
    <!-- will have access to scope $001 (but not $002) -->
    <div id="1.2"></div>

</div>
```

**2.**

To make things even more complicated, your directive creates an isolate scope, which means that any content it has will not see your directive's scope, but its parent scope. I.e. in the example above, DIV#1.1.1 will have access to scope $001, not $002.

What you can do about it (which basically mean, explicitly state that your directive's content should be included (transcluded) into its template. This gives you greater control on what's going on and allows you to bind the content of your directive to the scope you want (i.e. your directive's isolate scope).

---

The resulting code should look like this:

```
<div data-pj-catalog="{ 'type': 'Category1', 'key': '252' }">
    ...
    <div class="col-12">
        ...
        <span class="text-danger">{{query | json}}</span>
        <span class="text-danger">{{catalog.model | json}}</span>
        ...
    <div>
</div>

.directive('pjCatalog', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: 'CatalogCtrl',
        scope: {
            query: '@pjCatalog'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrls, transFn) {
            transFn(scope, function (cloned) {
                elem.empty().append(cloned);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBumu7qr409U0WCr1Sr7?p=preview)**.

---

<sub>**Note:**

This is considered "advanced" directive stuff (so it sounds (and is) much more complicated than most directive stuff) and should be required in rae cases only.

I am pretty sure there is a much easier way to achieve what you want (e.g. using a non-isolate scope) with slight modifications (but I am not sure *what* you want in order to help further.</sub>

Comment: Actually the reason I cannot use any transcluded content, neither any partials or template with the directive, is that I use Sitecore CMS with it's DMS feature which allows the user to edit content inline, so most of the content will be server side rendered fields which I cannot render through a template because it will break the CMS behaviour. But I do get your point and what I have done is I just created a not isolated scope and I moved all the logic from the ctrl inside the `link` function since my ctrl does not expose any API (Angular team suggests to use ctrls for exposing APIs).

Comment: I did follow your suggestion and simplified things a bit and that made it work, but I did not use any transclusion since the CMS does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Glad to know :) (I mean about things working out, not about the CMS not allowing transclusion) Indeed, if you remove the isolate scope and place the elements inside the directive it will work as expected.